# Performance analysis or Responsiveness analysis in R or Bash

Tags: r, bash

I am trying to evaluate the responsiveness of the task in between me and client A, in terms of the details field. That is the timeliness to be assessed in terms of a request sent to client A and the response received

I need to show the evaluation metric of this responsiveness in between me and client A in R or Bash script.

Attached is the sample of the data.

```
    Date           Time    Details
    29-05-2017  17:36:00    Sent to client A
    29-05-2017  20:00:00    received from client A
    30-05-2017  17:52:00    Sent to client A
    30-05-2017  18:00:00    Sent to client A
    30-05-2017  18:15:00    received from client A
    31-05-2017  11:30:00    Sent to client A
```

Comment: Your example shows some problems. Which of the two sendings (17:52 and 18:00) was received at 18:15  (supposing it was one of these two) ?

Comment: @fzd consider that for 17:52 sent the received is 18:15